# Query to fetch data between two characters in informix

Tags: database, informix

I have a value in informix which is like this :

```
value   AMOUNT: <15000000.00> USD
```

I need to fetch 15000000.00 afrom the above.

I am using this query to fetch the data between <> as workaround

```
select substring (value[15,40] 
from 1 for length (value[15,40]) -5  )  
from tablename p where value like 'AMOUNT%';
```

But, this is not generic as the lenght may vary.

Please help me with a generic query for this, fetch the data between <>.

The database I am using is Informix version 9.4.

Answer (score 1):

It's a diabolical problem, created by whoever chose to break one of the fundamental rules of database design: that the content of a column should be a single, indivisible value.

The best solution would be to modify the table to contain a value_descr = "AMOUNT", a value = 15000000.00, and a value_type = "USD", and ensure that the incoming data is stored in that fashion. Easier said than done, I know.

Failing that, you'll have to write a UDR that parses the string and returns the numeric portion of it. This would be feasible in SPL, but probably very slow. Something along the lines of:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE extract_value (inp VARCHAR(255)) RETURNING DECIMAL;
    DEFINE s SMALLINT;
    DEFINE l SMALLINT;
    DEFINE i SMALLINT;

    FOR i = 1 TO LENGTH(inp)
        IF SUBSTR(inp, i, 1) = "<" THEN
            LET s = i + 1;
        ELIF SUBSTR(inp, i, 1) = ">" THEN
            LET l = i - s - 1;
            RETURN SUBSTR(inp, s, l)::DECIMAL;
        END IF;
    END FOR;
    RETURN NULL::DECIMAL; -- could not parse out number
END PROCEDURE;
```

... which you would execute thus:

```
SELECT extract_value(p.value)
  FROM tablename AS p
  WHERE p.value LIKE 'AMOUNT%'
```

*NB: that procedure compiles and produces output in my limited testing on version 11.5. There is no validation done to ensure the string between the* `<>` *parses as a number. I don't have an instance of 9.4 handy, but I haven't used any features not available in 9.4 TTBOMK.*

Comment: @RET... Thanks a lot!!! But actually I was looking for a query rather than procedure. Though I handled this inside my esql code.

Comment: Procedure, function, the difference is only semantic. Later versions of Informix have a `CHAR_INDEX()` function, which would allow you to do this in a query, although it would still be pretty horrific. If you've solved it in esqlc on the consumption side you must be iterating through the data, which sounds suboptimal. Like I said at the beginning of my answer, fixing this at the data insert end would be the best solution.